# How to overwrite a variable from a parent class. I created an inheritance and I want values which are stated to have a different value

Tags: c#, variables, inheritance

I have created an inheritance class which is supposed to take the variables which do not have a value, and give them a value and pass through the new value in the parent class methods. This value is different to the parent class. I have tried stating the variable value by declaring it in Start(), however nothing else has fixed it. I get the console message

Warning CS0219  The variable 'shootDelay' is assigned but its value is never used'

Parent code

```
public class NPCAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum AIstate { Idle, Attacking }; //class that represents a group of constants
    public enum AiMoveDirection {Up, Down, Left, Right, Stop};

    public NPCController npcController;
    public AIstate aiState;
    public GameObject playerTarget;
    public float playerDistanceX;
    public float playerDistanceY;
    public float attackRange = 5.0f;

    public AiMoveDirection aiMoveDir;
    public float decisionTimer = 0f;
    private float decisionDelay;

    public NPCWeapon npcWeapon;
    public float shootTimer = 0f;
    private float shootDelay;
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        shootDelay = 0.2f;
        npcController = GetComponent<NPCController>();
        playerTarget = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        npcWeapon = GetComponent<NPCWeapon>();
    }
```

Child code

```
public class NPCAIFast : NPCAI
{
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Start()
    {
        float shootDelay = 0.00f;
        float decisionDelay = 0.1f;
    }
```

Comment: declare them as virtual?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary i have tried that, still getting 'variable shootDelay' error is assigned but its value is never used.

Comment: @urlreader do you mean the variables?

Comment: You need to make the field `protected`. `private` fields are not accessible from derived classes.

Comment: @KlausGütter in the child or parent code?

Comment: In the base class of course. Where you now have `private float shootDelay;`. See also [protected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected)

Comment: Your Start method is declaring new local variables and does not change the base members. Also consider setting the values in a constructor of your derived class.

Comment: @SeeDee do you mind showing what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In your parent class, use `protected float decisionDelay;` instead of `private float decisionDelay;`

and in your child class, you are declaring a new variable by writing `float shootDelay = 0.00f;`, instead remove the `float` and use `shootDelay = 0.00f;`

This is because the `private` modifier only allows the property to be accessed within the same class, if you want the subclass to access it, use the `protected` modifier.

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) for more info about modifier